# Android layout templates solution?

Tags: java, android

I'm developing Android app that will have a lot of dynamic layouts and views. It will be server driven: app will call server for specific data (probably in JSON) to display and I will need to display it accordingly (server response will consist of data such as type of layout, what kind of widgets will be there, resources to them such as images and so on). Is there any solution for easy and clean way to inject data object into layout that will fill specified placeholders (like eg. Handlebars library in javascript does)? I just want to avoid or reduce use of messy layout builders where everything is done programatically. Or maybe you have some clean solutions for that.
Thanks for response in advance!

Comment: I really don't know why that question was put in the "on hold" state. it's just question to experienced Android programmers on how they deal with such architectural problem. I don't demand code and ready solution, but tips on approach only.